# sparkR 1.4.0 : how to include jars

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, sparkr, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm trying to hook SparkR 1.4.0 up to Elasticsearch using the `elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.rc1.jar` jar file (found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop)). It's requiring a bit of hacking together, calling the `SparkR:::callJMethod` function.  I need to get a `jobj` R object for a couple of Java classes.  For some of the classes, this works:

```
SparkR:::callJStatic('java.lang.Class', 
                     'forName', 
                     'org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable')
```

But for others, it does not:

```
SparkR:::callJStatic('java.lang.Class', 
                     'forName', 
                     'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable')
```

Yielding the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat
```

It seems like Java isn't finding the `org.elasticsearch.*` classes, even though I've tried including them with the command line `--jars` argument, and the `sparkR.init(sparkJars = ...)` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if this is a question that more appropriately belongs on the actual SparkR issue tracker, could someone please point me to it?  I looked and was not able to find it.  Also, if someone knows an alternative way to hook `SparkR` up to `Elasticsearch`, I'd be happy to hear that as well.

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: There was a bug in the way jars specified with `--jars` were being used in SparkR. We had a fix checked in a couple of days ago at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7001. If you build Spark from the master branch you should be able to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've achieved it:

```
# environments, packages, etc ----
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/applications/spark-1.4.1")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

# connecting Elasticsearch to Spark via ES-Hadoop-2.1 ----
spark_context <- sparkR.init(master = "local[2]", sparkPackages = "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.1.0")
spark_sql_context <- sparkRSQL.init(spark_context)
spark_es <- read.df(spark_sql_context, path = "index/type", source = "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
printSchema(spark_es)
```

(Spark 1.4.1, Elasticsearch 1.5.1, ES-Hadoop 2.1 on OS X Yosemite)

The key idea is to link to the ES-Hadoop package and not the jar file, and to use it to create a Spark SQL context directly.

Comment: How to pass ES Host Name ?